# Capture Multiple images from the android camera

Tags: android

I want to capture multiple images from the camera in one time like facebook android application and show all the capture images in the gridview. i.e. say user clicked 5 photos continuously and show that 5 images in gridview. Please help me to complete this task.

Comment: I have two option 1) Photo upload from Camera & 2) Photo upload from Gallery. If user select the camera then photo should be clicked as much as user want and store it into sdcard after that I am opening the custom gallery and checked photos will be go for uploading..

Comment: In that case, you can check [Android – Select multiple photos from Gallery](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery/). Best luck

Comment: Can you help me how can I detect that camera Done button is clicked or not. i.e. If user open camera capture image and after that done button is enable in default camera application. If I want to do something in that done button of camera can I do that ? How ?

Comment: Sometimes effort and implementation rocks than thinking. So go and try to implement first without commenting here.

Answer (score 0):

A) Definitely after you take the Picture you need to ask your user

`Do you want to take more images Yes/ No`

B) If `Yes` start the `camera activity` again. Do remember you need to have a `counter`

C) Once he says `No`, start an `acitivity` which will have a `grid layout`. And populate that grid by the `counter` from the `camera activity`, programmatically

*Things to remember you need an array to store the name of the images taken by the user.*

Comment: I don't want to set yes / no dialog. After capturing image, camera should be remain opened

Comment: how will the camera close then??

Comment: With camera close button cancel